# ActiveAdmin like Rails Backend for CouchDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb, activeadmin, backend

I'm searching an ActiveAdmin like adminbackend for use with CouchDB. Is there something similar?

Comment: Would you please add a description of what you expect from such a tool for us non-ruby developers?

Comment: Basically, ActiveAdmin provides a nice, customizable gui with CRUD operations around your rails application's models.

Comment: You don't happen to mean *Futon*? Try to open `http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/` in your browser.

Comment: Futon is more like an admin interface for the database itself. With ActiveAdmin you can build an enduser admin backend for your app.

Comment: Got you now. Well, what @smathy said then.

Answer (score 2):

No, no such thing exists for CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

There is development in ActiveAdmin to become more database-agnostic, but most people are voting for MongoDB to be the first supported NoSQL database.  Go to ActiveAdmin's issue queue and search for the issue if you want to vote to influence things in a different way.